# Empty data Facebook insight

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

For some posts, hard to define how to reproduce the problem but it appears to be dark post (video or link) I am not able to get insight using the APIs

I am using a valid token page, tested on other posts

No matter what I try, for example :

`/pageid_postid/post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid_unique,post_impressions_by_paid_non_paid,post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique,post_story_adds_by_action_type,post_impressions_fan,post_impressions_fan_unique,post_impressions_fan_paid,post_impressions_fan_paid_unique,post_impressions_unique,post_impressions,post_impressions_viral_unique,post_impressions_viral_unique,post_video_avg_time_watched,post_video_length,post_video_views,post_video_views_unique,post_video_views_autoplayed,post_video_views_organic,post_video_views_organic_unique,post_video_views_paid,post_video_views_paid_unique,post_video_complete_views_organic,post_video_complete_views_paid,post_video_complete_views_30s_organic,post_video_complete_views_30s_paid,post_engaged_fan,post_video_retention_graph`

I simply get

`{
    "data" : []
}`

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is:

```
/pageid_post_id/insights?metric=post_impresions....
```